# list comprehension useless variable

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I found this on stackoverflow, it does exacly what I was looking for :

```
>>> k = [[1, 2], [4], [5, 6, 2], [1, 2], [3], [4]]
>>> import itertools
>>> k.sort()
>>> list(k for k,_ in itertools.groupby(k))
[[1, 2], [3], [4], [5, 6, 2]]
```

I don't understand the list comprehension here. If can't manage to translate it to `for iteration`. I always use the following syntax :

```
[k for k in smthiterable (if condition)]
```

I tried to change the underscore `_` to something else, it still work. But if I remove it, it doesn't. What is it's use?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate of either of those questions. The tuple unpacking may be adding to the confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`itertools.groupby` returns an iterable of *pairs* of items; in each pair you have the grouping key first and the items belonging to that group second.  The construct `for k,_ in iterable` unpacks those pairs, it's a direct analogy to how an assignment statement `k, _ = (0, 1)` can unpack a tuple object into two names.  The use of `_` as a variable name here is immaterial (this is a commonly used convention in Python to indicate that the value goes unused).

The code you've presented is not a particularly convincing use of `groupby`, since the group object is discarded and only the unique keys were used.

The list comprehension below is more Pythonic, it avoids creating the "useless variable":

```
>>> [list(x) for x in sorted(set(map(tuple, k)))]
[[1, 2], [3], [4], [5, 6, 2]]
```

Comment: I use it to discard duplicate in my list of list. You list comprehension is nice, I tried something like it, but couldn't manage to make it work. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The underscore (`_`) is really like any other variable, it's not special syntax. Pretend that it's an `x` if it's confusing you. The underscore is typically used to denote an "unused" variable. `itertools.groupby` returns an iterable, where each iteration returns another iterable (each of these latter iterables happens to always have two elements). So the `k, _` syntax is simply doing tuple unpacking (see here: https://chrisalbon.com/python/unpacking_a_tuple.html).

`k` will be the first element of each iterable (and the second is assigned to `_`).

Here's the condensed example from the link for convenience (and in case the link dies):

```
soldiers = [('Steve', 'Miller'), ('Stacy', 'Markov'), ('Sonya', 'Matthews')]
for _, last_name in soldiers:
    # print the second element
    print(last_name)
```

outputs:

```
Miller
Markov
Matthews
```